# Location of Ubuntu/Unity 22.10 window controls

Tags: unity, ubuntu-unity

On Ubuntu/Unity 22.10, is it possible to change the location of window controls to the right?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. As far as I know, the answer is No.